# Convert JSON file to CSV file with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following JSON file:

```
    {
    "took": 17,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 25,
        "successful": 25,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 3,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "w106941",
                "_type": "wqr",
                "_id": "51929",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "tstamp": "1978-12-06T23:00:00Z",
                    "value": 41,
                    "name": "SO4-Dis",
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "w6406931",
                "_type": "wqr",
                "_id": "51929",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "tstamp": "1979-12-11T23:00:00Z",
                    "value": 45,
                    "name": "SO4",
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "w2049185",
                "_type": "wqr",
                "_id": "51929",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "tstamp": "1980-12-22T23:00:00Z",
                    "value": 48,
                    "name": "T-D2",
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to create a `csv` with the following format in **python**:

```
tstamp;value;name;

1978-12-06T23:00:00Z;41;SO4-Dis;

1979-12-11T23:00:00Z;45;SO4;

1980-12-22T23:00:00Z;48;T-D2;
```

I tried all codes in this page.
Also I tried with `pandas df`.

```
df = pd.read_json("example.json")
df_hits=df['hits']
#df = df.loc[["sta_no_s", "wqtr_tstamp_ts", "part_shortname_s"]]
df_hits.to_csv("sample.csv", index=False, sep=';')
f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w+"))

# Write CSV Header, If you dont need that, remove this line
f.writerow(["tstamp", "value", "name"])


for x in df:
    f.writerow([df["hits"]["tstamp"],
            df["hits"]["value"],
            df["hits"]["name"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = response.json()['hits']
response.json()
result_hits = result['hits']
# open a file for writing
sample = open('sample.csv', 'w')
# create the csv writer object without \n

csvwriter = csv.writer(sample,delimiter=';',lineterminator='\n',)

count = 0


for x in result_hits:
source=x['_source']
print(source)
if count == 0:
         header = source.keys()
         csvwriter.writerow(header)
         count += 1
  csvwriter.writerow(source.values())
```

sample.close()